# Loading a zip file, converting ".docx" into a text file, exporting back in R

Tags: r

I am trying to load a zip file into R. This zip file has hundreds of ".docx" documents in it. I want to convert each of these ".docx" documents into a ".txt" file.

Is there any way to automate this process in R?

The zip file is called "Documents.zip"!

Comment: I don't have experience with it, but a quick search on google suggested [`officer`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/officer/vignettes/officer_reader.html). This question is specifically [off-topic for StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), I suggest you look around [SoftwareRecs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code below, you can get a data.frame with content of your documents stored in "Documents.zip".

```
library(officer)
library(purrr)
library(magrittr)


docx_scan_data <- unpack_folder("Documents.zip", folder = "docx_zips") %>% 
  list.files(pattern = "\\.docx$", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE) %>% 
  map_df(function(x) {
    data <- read_docx(path = x) %>% 
      docx_summary()
    data$path <- x 
    data
  })
```

It should be easy then to create text files from the result. Text content is stored in column `text`.

Comment: Hey David, thanks for the response! How do I exactly take each file and then covert it? I was thinking about creating a loop using the "write.table(data.frame_" function, but I don't know if that's the right way to approach it.

Comment: Also I keep getting an error saying Error: unexpected '}' in "            }"

Comment: The script is only reading docx files found in a zip file and return all docx content as a data.frame.